# doubt about way to lock a boost mutex

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

```
boost::recursive_mutex m;
m.lock();
```

versus

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock( mutex_ );
```

Is there an advantage to use the first Form? Does the second form only provide RAII mecanism, or are there others advantages ?

Comment: Yes, it "only" provides RAII, but that is enough.  No, there is no advantage to the first form.

Comment: @Nemo: although the RAII mechanism is much safer and cleaner, it's a little limiting.  It is possible that you would want to lock a mutex in a function call and have it unlocked in another function call.  Then, you'll have to `new` the `lock_guard`, which feels even more dirty than the `.lock()` solution.

Comment: @André:  True, strictly speaking.  But if you are locking it in one function and unlocking it in another, then you probably need a redesign.  The whole point of RAII is that it makes it easy to _prove_ that no resources are leaked.  It is worth significant design effort to make it possible to use this idiom, IMO.

Comment: @André: Then the lock should be acquired at a higher level and it should be using RAII.

Comment: @Martin: Suppose you're writing a GUI application.  It's possible to think one GUI callback will acquire the mutex lock and another callback release it (based on user actions).  In such a case, you can't push the lock at a higher level (e.g. out of the event loop) as that would lock it for the whole application, defeating the purpose.  @Nemo: I totally agree that RAII is 110% worth it. However, this restriction is intended to encourage people to use RAII-based locking.  *Forcing* clients to use that in *all* circumstances is short-sighted IMHO.

Comment: @André Caron: There will always be exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of using lock_guard is that it will release the lock when it goes out of scope. This eliminates the need to manually release the lock and reduces the chance of forgetting to do so.

```
boost::recursive_mutex mylock;

{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock( mylock );

    // do something

    if(false == do_something())
    {
        return; // "lock" goes out of scope and unlocks 'mylock' from it's destructor.
    }

}
// "lock" has gone out of scope and unlocked 'mylock' from it's destructor.
```

Comment: +1.  And note that this is exactly the sort of code someone is liable to add at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The two forms are not equivalent in the least. Here's what's equivalent* to the second form:

```
boost::recursive_mutex m;
m.lock();
try {
    // ...
} catch(...) {
    m.unlock();
    throw;
}
m.unlock();
```

This is what you call "only" providing RAII: avoiding hideous boilerplate to provide the same level of correctness.

*: with caveats; see other answers & comments

Comment: Even that is not equivalent; see @Chet's "early return" example.